# Unable to load the EJB module error on deployment when Logback is used

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, logback

I am playing around with Java EE for the first time and I am able to get a hello world app to work with both a web client and console client calling an ejb.

After I confirmed the code was working I added a logger using logback for logging purposes. Once I added the logger in my code I get the following error, if I remove logback the error goes away.

**Is there any way I can have logback running on EJB's?**

--Edit--

Apparently **yes**: [The logback demo page](http://logback.qos.ch/demo.html) lists an example with a web application.

--End Edit--

As a side note: The only deployment that fails is web, a client console application works fine.

Error I am getting:

```
deploy?DEFAULT=C:\Users\roberth\Programming_Projects\NetBeans\WebInterface\build\web&name=WebInterface&contextroot=/WebInterface&force=true failed on GlassFish Server 3+ 
 Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Unable to load the EJB module. DeploymentContext does not contain any EJB. Check the archive to ensure correct packaging for C:\Users\roberth\Programming_Projects\NetBeans\WebInterface\build\web.
If you use EJB component annotations to define the EJB, and an ejb or web deployment descriptor is also used, please make sure that the deployment descriptor references a Java EE 5 or higher version schema, and that the metadata-complete attribute is not set to true, so the component annotations can be processed as expected. Please see server.log for more details.
C:\Users\roberth\Programming_Projects\NetBeans\WebInterface\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1060: The module has not been deployed.
```

Stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer prepare method
SEVERE: Exception while preparing the app
SEVERE: Unable to load the EJB module. DeploymentContext does not contain any EJB. Check the archive to ensure correct packaging for C:\Users\roberth\Programming_Projects\NetBeans\WebInterface\build\web.
If you use EJB component annotations to define the EJB, and an ejb or web deployment descriptor is also used, please make sure that the deployment descriptor references a Java EE 5 or higher version schema, and that the metadata-complete attribute is not set to true, so the component annotations can be processed as expected
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load the EJB module. DeploymentContext does not contain any EJB. Check the archive to ensure correct packaging for C:\Users\roberth\Programming_Projects\NetBeans\WebInterface\build\web.
If you use EJB component annotations to define the EJB, and an ejb or web deployment descriptor is also used, please make sure that the deployment descriptor references a Java EE 5 or higher version schema, and that the metadata-complete attribute is not set to true, so the component annotations can be processed as expected
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.prepare(EjbDeployer.java:201)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE: Exception while preparing the app : Unable to load the EJB module. DeploymentContext does not contain any EJB. Check the archive to ensure correct packaging for C:\Users\roberth\Programming_Projects\NetBeans\WebInterface\build\web.
If you use EJB component annotations to define the EJB, and an ejb or web deployment descriptor is also used, please make sure that the deployment descriptor references a Java EE 5 or higher version schema, and that the metadata-complete attribute is not set to true, so the component annotations can be processed as expected
```